# Looping over a multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to list plugins that have an update available in wordpress. Ideally it would look like:
"plugin name" "current version" "available update version"
e.g. "real-media-library-lite" "4.9.0" "4.11.0"

so far im getting the data i need (apart from the current version) like so:

```
$update_plugins = get_site_transient( 'update_plugins' );

 if ( ! empty( $update_plugins->response ) )
    var_dump($update_plugins->response );
```

which outputs the following:

```
array(3) {
    ["real-media-library-lite/index.php"]=> object(stdClass)#8563 (12) {
        ["id"]=> string(37) "w.org/plugins/real-media-library-lite"
        ["slug"]=> string(23) "real-media-library-lite"
        ["plugin"]=> string(33) "real-media-library-lite/index.php"
        ["new_version"]=> string(6) "4.11.0"
        ["url"]=> string(54) "https://wordpress.org/plugins/real-media-library-lite/"
        ["package"]=> string(66) "https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/real-media-library-lite.zip"
        ["icons"]=> array(2) {
            ["2x"]=> string(76) "https://ps.w.org/real-media-library-lite/assets/icon-256x256.gif?rev=2293211"
            ["1x"]=> string(76) "https://ps.w.org/real-media-library-lite/assets/icon-128x128.gif?rev=2293211"
        }
        ["banners"]=> array(2) {
            ["2x"]=> string(79) "https://ps.w.org/real-media-library-lite/assets/banner-1544x500.png?rev=2251436"
            ["1x"]=> string(78) "https://ps.w.org/real-media-library-lite/assets/banner-772x250.png?rev=2251436"
        }
        ["banners_rtl"]=> array(0) {
        }
        ["tested"]=> string(3) "5.6"
        ["requires_php"]=> string(5) "7.0.0"
        ["compatibility"]=> object(stdClass)#8555 (0) {
        }
    }
    ["advanced-custom-fields-pro/acf.php"]=> object(stdClass)#8557 (8) {
        ["slug"]=> string(26) "advanced-custom-fields-pro"
        ["plugin"]=> string(34) "advanced-custom-fields-pro/acf.php"
        ["new_version"]=> string(5) "5.9.3"
        ["url"]=> string(36) "https://www.advancedcustomfields.com"
        ["tested"]=> string(5) "5.5.3"
        ["package"]=> string(0) ""
        ["icons"]=> array(1) {
            ["default"]=> string(63) "https://ps.w.org/advanced-custom-fields/assets/icon-256x256.png"
        }
        ["banners"]=> array(2) {
            ["low"]=> string(77) "https://ps.w.org/advanced-custom-fields/assets/banner-772x250.jpg?rev=1729102"
            ["high"]=> string(78) "https://ps.w.org/advanced-custom-fields/assets/banner-1544x500.jpg?rev=1729099"
        }
    }
    ["real-media-library/index.php"]=> object(stdClass)#8560 (7) {
        ["slug"]=> string(18) "real-media-library"
        ["new_version"]=> string(6) "4.11.0"
        ["package"]=> NULL
        ["id"]=> int(0)
        ["url"]=> string(47) "https://devowl.io/wordpress-real-media-library/"
        ["tested"]=> string(3) "5.6"
        ["plugin"]=> string(28) "real-media-library/index.php"
    }
}
```

what I can't seem to figure out is how to loop over this array and output the "slug" and the "new_version", heck i can't even output the values of the first dimension of the array dynamically.
So far i was only able to get to the data i need like this:

```
$update_plugins = get_site_transient( 'update_plugins' );
$slug = $update_plugins->response;
 print_r($slug["real-media-library-lite/index.php"]->slug);
```

but i need to output the data dynamically. any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply iterating over the response array and outputting the `slug` and `new_version` properties can be done using a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($update_plugins->response as $plugin_name => $plugin_object) {
    var_dump($plugin_object->slug);
    var_dump($plugin_object->new_version);
}
```